# Множественное число от слова "церковь".

Tags: грамматика

Здравтвуйте.
Возможна ли форма им. п.  мн. ч.  **церква**? Где-то встретила *Церква звенят колоколами*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В некоторых диалектах слово **церква** - мужского рода.

> ЦЕРКОВЬ
> **муж. церква**, южн., зап., новг. место, здание для христианского богослужения, храм, Божий храм. (словарь Даля)

В словарь Даля каждый может заглянуть, в Нацкорпус - тоже :

> Ф. Д. Крюков. К источнику исцелений // «Русское Богатство», 1904
> ― **Чи церква осматривать**, чи до Городка ходить, ― сказал он, обращаясь к своим спутникам.
>
> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1958)
> Господь благословит! **Церква закрывают**… Попам житья нету…
>
> А зараз получается так, что Сталин этих местных коммунистов, какие народ силком загоняли в колхоз и **церква без спросу закрывали**, кроет почем зря, с должностей смещает.
>
> ― То-то и есть, что не все одно: **церква позакрывали**, попов окулачили…

ЦЕрква - м.р., ед.ч. (южн., зап., новг., см. словарь Даля)
церквА - мн.ч. (см. примеры)

Comment: А могло неодушевленное существительное м.р. иметь окончание А в начальной форме? В настоящее время все сущ. м. р. на А/Я являются только одушевленными.

Comment: Надо изучить этот вопрос!

Comment: Скорее всего, путаница в разных изданиях словаря Даля слегка замутила наше расследование. Остается констатировать, что цЕрква - ед.ч. ж.р., церквА - мн.ч. в просторечии, о чем свидетельствуют литературные цитаты. Свой ответ исправлять не стал, форма *церква* мн.ч. остается неким исключением в парадигме...

Comment: Михаил Катков :  
>Монастыри, церква кресты скрестив  
Звонят по всей Руси необозримой...  
И веет древней мудростью от ив,  
Когда проходишь по тропинке мимо.

http://stroki.net/content/view/7063/41/

Comment: Интересно, что неод. сущ. с ув. суффиксом ИН (домина, дымина, холодина, голосина)как-то НЕУЮТНО ЧУВСТВУЮТ СЕБЯ  в  ЧУЖОМ ДЛЯ НИХ 1-ом (школьном) склонении: "Существительные муж. р. на -ина с ув. знач. типа домина изменяются по 2 скл., выступая при этом в им. п. и во всех косв. пад., кроме вин., как сущ. то муж., то жен. р.: им. п.: этот и эта домина; род. п.: этого и этой домины; дат. п.: этому и этой домине; тв. п.: этим и этой доминой; предл. п.: об этом и об этой домине. В вин. п. нормальна только форма на -у с согласованием по жен. р. (эту домину)".

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1173-1193.html

Comment: Вопрос с мужским родом закрыт, произошла путаница с пометами в словаре Даля, бывает. Исключительная форма мн.ч. *церква* достойна внимательного рассмотрения филологами.  
>М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. (1960)  
― Вы, гражданы, не волнуйтесь, дойдет дело и до разных и тому подобных любвей, **это не вопрос**.

Можно предположить, что у слова ц*лЮбвя* была бы форма мн.ч. - *любвЯ*.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, это результат ошибочного смешения форм. Согласно "Орфографическому словарю" допустимы два варианта: церквями и церквами. Согласно толковым словарям существует слово "цЕрква". Церковь - церквями, церква - церквами. Наверное, из них образовалась контаминация "церквА".

Comment: >Согласно толковым словарям существует слово "цЕрква".

Причём, хочу отдельно подчернуть, что это **единственное**, а не множественное число.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре В.А.Чудинова  "Расшифровка славянского слогового и буквенного письма в строке за № 1839.читаем: ЦРКВА (№136) – множественное число существительного ЦЕРКОВЬ.

Кроме того в речи сельских жителей я неоднократно слышал именно такой вариант множественного числа(например,"старые церква строились по-другому").

Конечно, сейчас это слово следует считать устаревшим и просторечным, оно действительно может встретиться очень редко.

Comment: Если бы это не не Чудинов, я бы поверил.
Или это другой?

Да нет, вроде других не было. Да еше - В.А.

Вот насчет народной формы - это поинтереснее будет. 
Но настолько противоестественно тут эта форма на -А для женского рода, да еще полностью омонимичная с единственным числом...
Может это все-таки единственное было, а вы недослышали?

Comment: "а вы недослышали?" Уточню, это было в детстве(50-е годы), Мичуринский район, Тамбовская область.

Словарь Чудинова  http://chudinov.ru/slovar-russkih-i-etrusskih-slov/12/

Comment: P.S.  церквА - ударение на последний слог, так что "полностью омонимичная" не получается.

Comment: Именно так. На последний. В единственном. Как "морква". 
А Вы во множественном как слышали? Неужели не на последний?

>я недочитала))))  
  
Что сие значит?

Comment: ЦЕрква - м.р., ед.ч.
церквА - мн.ч.

Comment: > Может это все-таки единственное было, а вы недослышали?
Посчитала, что вопрос адресован мне. Слово "недочитала", конечно, следовало взять в кавыччки.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, окончание "А" нехарактерно для ж.р., но можно представить такую последовательность: цЕрква (ед.ч.) - цЕрквы (мн.ч.) - церквА (мн.ч.).

То есть изменение происходило по аналогии с вариантами окончаний м.р., где Ы/И - основное окончание, а А/Я - его вариант (обычно разг.).

Да и сходное слово "морква", которую мы воспринимаем как собирательное сущ. ед.ч., в разговорной речи могла считаться формой мн.числа.

Comment: мОрква или морквА?

Comment: В разных диалектах: мОрква-морквА

http://5fan.ru/wievjob.php?id=47018

Comment: МорквА и церквА.
Других вариантов я не слыхивал.
Хотя если они действительно зафиксированы, то это несколько меняет дело.

Comment: И цЕрква(ед.ч.), и церквА(мн.ч.) совсем недавно были обычными словами в просторечных говорах средней полосы и Юга. См. ответ Дезкого.Цитата из Крюкова: "Наши богомольцы постояли в раздумье и пошли дальше.
   - Да-да... вот какой порядок... - говорил Алексей невесело. - А вы, дидусю, митрополита? Х-хе-хе... навряд ли придется... Нашему брату и в рай очереди долго ждать...
   - Ну... куда же теперь? - сказал отец Егора. Алексей, который взял на себя роль руководителя, остановился и задумался.
   - Чи церквА осматривать, чи до Городка ходить, - сказал он, обращаясь к своим спутникам."

Comment: Грумант не дает ссылок, а веры ему - сами понимаете.
Да и вопрос не в том. Ударение в единственном на первоу слоге "цЕрква" Вы как-нибудь можете подтвердить? У меня соверщенно не на слуху.
Ссылка на Крюкова, если что
http://fedor-krjukov.narod.ru/proza/K_istochniku_isceleniy.htm

Comment: Ну, я из этого же произведения и цитирую. Не понял про Груманта.Смотрите ответ Дерзкого Grantum, он расширил его, добавил цитаты из Шолохова. У меня как раз "на слуху" и цЕрква и церквА. Так же как и церкОвь, и церковА. Слышал множество раз. "В словарь Даля каждый может заглянуть, в Нацкорпус - тоже"(Дерзкий)

Comment: Это я про Груманта про не понял. Вы на него ссылаетесь, а у него информативности - ноль. 
Не буду я его ответы опять смотреть, надоело уже. Своими словами можете передать?

Что касается ударения, да я нашел у Фасмера, так что этот аргумент я снимаю. Остается главный. По какой парадигме такое могло получиться. Хоть какой-то,Ю пусть отдаленный аналог. Не бывает в языке таких непонятных изолированных флуктуаций.

Comment: Снова не понял. Не ссылался я на Груманта.Я говорил о примерах персонажа под ником "Дерзкий Grantum".Вы перепутали ники, уважаемый Бегемотус.
Михаил Катков(современный поэт,живет в Москве, родом из Рязанских краев, совсем близко от моей тамбовщины) :

Монастыри, церква кресты скрестив
Звонят по всей Руси необозримой...
И веет древней мудростью от ив,
Когда проходишь по тропинке мимо.

http://stroki.net/content/view/7063/41/

Comment: >под ником "Дерзкий Grantum".Вы перепутали ники, уважаемый Бегемотус.   
  
Щазззз. Перепутал. Не смешите, уважаемый. 
За сим, простите. Если Вы на подобную аргументацию переходите, вынужден откланяться.

Answer (score 0):

хм... ну вообще-то "церкви" можете употреблять без страха ошибиться.. "Церква" скорее всего есть литературный изыск автора. Или какой-нибудь устаревший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, множественное никак тут никак не получается.
Даже в предположении, что это собирательное (морква=морковь) все равно единственное.

Хотя, конечно, есть некоторые сложности с этим исторически переходом (сравните морковь но брюква от моркы и брюкы соответвенно), множественное число все-таки с "а" странновато все-таки... Нет аналогов.

//==================  22.03.2014

Что-то я не догадался сразу в Фасмера посмотреть.
Он даёт вариант единственного с ударением на первом слоге.

Происходит от зап.-герм. *kirika из др.-греч. (предположительно). Источником герм. слов является греч. κυρικόν из κυριακόν. Исторически более оправданная др.-в.-нем. этимология сопряжена с бо́льшими фонетическими трудностями, чем объяснение из готск. Неприемлема этимология из др.-сакс. kirikа или др.-сканд.* kirka. Точно так же неприемлемо толкование как заимств. через народнолат. *суriса или непосредственно из греч. κυρικόν. Отсюда: др.-русск. цьркы (род. п. -ъве), ст.-слав. црькы (др.-греч. ἐκκλησία, ναός), русск. церковь (народн. це́рква), укр. це́рква, белор. це́рква, болг. цръ́ква, че́рква, сербохорв. цр̑ква, словенск. cèrkǝv, польск. cerkiew, н.-луж. сеrkеj, полабск. саrḱоi, саrḱеv. Отличный хронологический слой представляют чешск.-церк.-слав. циръкы (род. п. -ъве; Киевск. листки, Рs. Sin.), др.-словенск. circuvah, местн. мн. (Фрейзинг. отрывки), чешск. církev, в.-луж. суrkеj. Источник предполагают в готск.-арианск.* kirikô «церковь» или в др.-бав. kirkô — стадия, предшествующая др.-в.-нем. chirihha.Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Так что одно мое возражение о синонимичности форм снимается. 
Но только одно. 
Сомнение относительно грамматической возможности множественного с окончание -А по-прежнему остаются. Хотя бы аналог какой.

Вот есть просторечная форма родительного единственного "путя" (от путь), но не помню, чтоб она могла использоваться как множественное. А больше и в голову что-то ничего не приходит...